# How do I get twilio to push the button 9 upon a call?

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to set it up as a buzzer answering machine so when someone buzzes up, if it's between 9am and 5pm, it just pushes the button 9 and lets them up otherwise it dials my number.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To play DTMF tones you can use the  verb as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Response>
    <Play digits="wwww9"></Play>
</Response>
```

Each `w` represents a wait period of 0.5 seconds. This lets you adjust the timing of when the digits begin playing to suit the phone system you are dialing.

Hope this helps you